# Pulling hidden files in Android SD Card

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-file

I am trying to implement image caching system in android, the caching use both, caching in memory and also using **android external storage**. In the external storage I create some hidden files, for example `.nomedia` and any other file prefixed with `.`, and I put all my caching related files in one folder, the problem is, when I use android file explorer in `ddms` to pull all files in my folder, **only the non hidden files are pulled**, I even can't see the hidden files in ddms file explorer. So is there anyway to **show and pull hidden files in android external storage**? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, rather than using click expand mouse oriented file exploration, why dont you just traverse your hidden files from the command line? try this http://www.streamhead.com/android-tutorial-sd-card/

Comment: I managed to pull them all using adb pull {pathtodirectory}, thanks adam :)