# DDMS Android File Explorer display dot folders

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

How do you get the File Explorer in DDMS to display folders that start with a dot.

For example, /mnt/.test does not show up in DDMS. Is there a way to display it?

I am aware that I can manipulate these files with `adb shell`. I'm asking if there is a way to do this with DDMS.

**Edit:**
I submitted a patch to fix this in DDMS: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/37801/
Basically you can rebuild ddmlib with the patch and drop it into eclipse and you will be able to see files and folders starting with a dot.

**Edit 2:**
I've uploaded the patched [ddmlib.jar](http://carlosrendon.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ddmlib.jar) since building Android just for this patch is a ton of work.

To use, you just need to figure out where eclipse is loading this jar from and put it there. On my windows machine it is `eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\355\1\.cp\libs`.

Comment: If you want to badly enough, ddms is open source...

Comment: @ChrisStratton sure, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything first.

Comment: Your ddmlib.jar broke my DDMS on my Mac: http://cl.ly/image/352L2F0B1I3i :(

Comment: @Markive Sorry :( ... my patch comes with no guarantees...

Comment: No that's fine, it's just a warning really for other mac users..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like *at minimum* you would need to do something like change

```
Thread t = new Thread("ls " + entry.getFullPath()) { //$NON-NLS-1$
```

to

```
Thread t = new Thread("ls -a" + entry.getFullPath()) { //$NON-NLS-1$
```

In the getChildren() method and a similar change to ls -la in the doLsAndThrow() method of com.android.ddmlib.FileListingService within the DDMS sources.

You may also have to make changes elsewhere for results beginning with a . to be fully handled.

(personally, I'll stick to the shell)

Comment: Thanks for the head-start on this. The line you have highlighted here just names the thread. The line in doLsAndThrow() is the actual shell command used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is easily possible. See this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838880/pulling-hidden-files-in-android-sd-card). More info [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands).

Their solution is to traverse files using the command line. Give that a try.